# How to delete pattern from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do this query in "Document varchar(max)"

```
Select * from myTable
where Document
like '%Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.%'
```

I have in my database something like this (without , and .)

```
Document:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
```

My question is: **How can i remove , and . from search text?**

Comment: Do you mean you need to make `,` and `.` optional? To remove them you can just edit the query.

Comment: If you can help it, you should do it in your application because if you have a lot of records in your table, the performance going to be horrible. grab everything by the first word and sort it out in application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
where replace(replace(Document, ',', ''), '.', '') like
      replace(replace('%Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit.%', ',', ''), '.', '')
```

Comment: I already tried. This replace , and . from field in database, dont work for input search.

Comment: @RaulEscalona . . .  You can use the same method to remove them from the search string.